# index.php is not removed properly codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My .htaccess location:

```
website_folder/ 
    –––– application/ 
    –––– assets/ 
    –––– system/ 
    –––– user_guide/ 
    ---- .htaccess <-------------------------
    –––– index.php 
    –––– license.txt
```

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have created total 5 controller, 4 of them working smoothly without index.php. 
**e.g. `http://localhost/website_folder/login` is working fine.**

But I have another controller

> named student is not working without index.php. e.g.
>   `http://localhost/website_folder/index.php/student`

I dont want index.html to be here.

Please help. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Filename is capitalized i.e. `Student_controller || Student_c || Student`? Class name is as same as file name?

Comment: both are same and capitalized.

Comment: Sometimes it is cached in browser. First try wit Apache restart, than open another browser i.e. if you are using Chrome, now try in Firefox, also in Private browsing window would be prefferable.

Comment: Add `RewriteBase /website_folder` after `RewriteEngine On` when running at `localhost` and just `RewriteBase /` when you upload the code to a hosting service.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hicaro, I have tried with 'RewriteBase /website_folder' its working, Once again thank you so much :)

Comment: Use it with slash at the end like `RewriteBase /website_folder/`.

Answer (score 0):

Open your application/config/config.php and change this code:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

into

```
$config['index_page']=""
```